# Handle Custom User Model Django-Allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have a **custom User Model** that extends from Django's `User` and I want to register that user model instead of only the default one.

For this, I am using the `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS` setting as per [allauth doc](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html).

This is what I have in **settings.py**:

```py
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'myapp.forms.SignupForm'
```

And in **myapp/forms.py**:

```py
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = MyUser

    def signup(self, request, user):
        print('test')
        user.save()
        MyUser(user=user).save()
```

The `signup()` function should be executed:

> This class [SignupForm] should implement a def signup(self, request, user) method, where user represents the newly signed up user.

But it isn't (`test` is not printed). Only *User* is saved, *MyUser* isn't.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing 2 things here:

1. You're using `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS` in order to tell `all-auth` what custom signup form to use
2. Your custom signup form is inheriting from django's own `UserCreationForm`

In this way `signup()` method will never be invoke.

If you have a look at [this line](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/forms.py#L405) you'll see that there's the place where the `signup()` method is invoked.
So, if you want to fully leverage `all-auth`'s built-in forms, I'd recommend you inherit `SignupForm` from `all-auth` library.

Yet again, judging by your approach, you might wanna consider setting `AUTH_USER_MODEL=MyUser`.

Comment: The `AUTH_USER_MODEL` approach worked after a bit of tweaking. Thank you so much!